# How to use Sound with Toast in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, toast

I want to play a sound when my toast pops up in my android app.

Here is my code for the toast in my main class:

```
private void workEndNotification() {
    //Custom Toast notification for the Work End Reminder.
    LayoutInflater inflaterWork = getLayoutInflater();
    View toastLayout = inflaterWork.inflate(R.layout.work_notification_toast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_root_view));
    TextView header = (TextView) toastLayout.findViewById(R.id.toast_header);
    header.setText("Work Day Over Soon!");
    final Toast toastWork = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
    toastWork.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toastWork.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toastWork.setView(toastLayout);
    toastWork.show();

    myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            toastWork.cancel();
        }
    }, 1);
};
```

Here is the sound code in my SoundPool class (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidMedia/article.html):

```
class PlaySound extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private SoundPool soundPool;
private int soundID;
boolean loaded = false;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.work_notification_toast);
    View view = findViewById(R.id.toast_header);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
    // Set the hardware buttons to control the music
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    // Load the sound
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,int status) {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });
    soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // Getting the user sound settings
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
        // Is the sound loaded already?
        if (loaded) {
            soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
            Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

I know I am not calling it in my toast method, and I know that I am using a touchview. How can I make it so the sound appears only when the toast appears, at the same time that is. I have been trying, but have not managed.

I don't want a touch or anything. Just for it to play with the toast simply.

Answer (score 2):

Make a function like this

```
private void playSound(int resId){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, resId);
       mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });
    mp.start();
}
```

and call it where you are displaying your `Toast` like this

```
playSound(R.raw.sound);
```

You also need to replace the resource so it matches yours

**EDIT: You seem to want to play several sounds. You can make a simple sound pool on your own**

Make a int array or resource you want to play like this and listen for when the `MediaPlayer` is done with playing, tell him to play the next one until it played the last one in the array.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {


    private final int[] soundResources = {R.raw.sound1, R.raw.sound2, R.raw.sound3};
    private int counter = 0;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        playSound(counter);
    }

    private void playSound(int resId){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestActivity.this, resId);
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        if(counter < soundResources.length ) {
            playSound(soundResources[++counter]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! In regards to the touch view, I do not know if I should keep this or not. It seems unnecessary to keep it.

Comment: You can set the volume with your code. If you want to set volume you can set it when you play it with your Toast

Comment: Oh, and, If i added more sounds into my raw. Like sound2, sound 3. How would I put these in my soundpool class? Like this?
     soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);
     soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound2, 1);

Comment: `SoundPool` stands for playing short sounds of WAV PCM format and the soundfile size should not exeed 1Mb in size. If you need to play something "bigger" like a music then you should use `MediaPlayer`. `MediaPlayer` could play only one file at a time and its initialization for playing file is shown in this answer. If you need to play other file just pass other file/resource name in `MediaPlayer.create()`

Comment: I have made a sample sound pool with MediaPlayer... check it out

Comment: Thanks, well I just want to play 1 sound for 1 toast. Ex: sound1.ogg plays for toast1, sound2.ogg plays for toast2. I got it working by simply doing:

    -soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1);  (the first sound1.ogg file i had)
    -soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound2, 1); (i just added a line under it for the sound2.ogg in my raw folder)

Comment: Ok now I made it really simple. just use the function playSound according to your sounds like playSound(R.raw.sound1) or playSoung(R.raw.sound2) ...

Comment: What is the difference between your implementation and my solution of just adding the line soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound2, 1); for each of my sounds?

Comment: look at @Stan's comment