# Android Toast with sound

Tags: java, android

I did  Toast message in text view. i want to include sound over that toast message.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"This is my toast message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// Set your own toast  message
        }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. It seems like your question may not be a question, nor be relevant. Please rephrase it.
Also, SO is not the right place to ask other developers to make your job, or what you want. If you have any problem, we will be happy to help you. But if you want to be spoonfed, then it is not the right place. 
Thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to play the sound using **`MediaPlayer`** every time you show the **`Toast`**

**Step 1**. Put The Sound File(The Sound You Want To Play While Showing **`Toast`**)
in *`res/raw/abc.mp3`*

[image: Something Like This]

It Should Look Something Like This.

**Step 2**. Play The Sound While Showing **`Toast`**

```
 private void showToast(String text){
       Toast.makeText(this,text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// this = Context
       MediaPlayer mediaplayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.abc);//You Can Put Your File Name Instead Of abc
           mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });
        mediaplayer.start();
    }
```

The Output Should Show Something Like This
[image]

Comment: thank you Shashank Mishra.Could you please send screen of this output

Comment: How Are You Going To Hear The Sound On Screenshot? But Still, As You Wish. Please Tick As Right Answer If This Helps You, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Function for playsound:**

```
private void playSound(int resId){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, resId);
       mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    });
    mp.start();
}
```

Then you want to display toast, you can also call the function:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
playSound(R.raw.sound);
```

You must have to keep sound in android `res/raw/` folder.

[Referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831737/how-to-use-sound-with-toast-in-android)

Thank you!

Comment: thank you Hasib Akter. i'm new to android so it is hard to understand.

Comment: Thank you also, I already edit post to understand you easily.
I this can help you mark my answare as correct answere and if you have any query fell free tell me.